# Trying to understand the usage of function pointer

Tags: c, linux, u-boot

This is the function in [u-boot's bootm.c](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/blob/master/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c) from where the kernel is launched:

```
/* Subcommand: GO */
static void boot_jump_linux(bootm_headers_t *images, int flag)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_ARM64
void (*kernel_entry)(void *fdt_addr);
int fake = (flag & BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO);

kernel_entry = (void (*)(void *fdt_addr))images->ep;

debug("## Transferring control to Linux (at address %lx)...\n",
(ulong) kernel_entry);
bootstage_mark(BOOTSTAGE_ID_RUN_OS);

announce_and_cleanup(fake);

if (!fake)
kernel_entry(images->ft_addr);
#else
unsigned long machid = gd->bd->bi_arch_number;
char *s;
void (*kernel_entry)(int zero, int arch, uint params);
unsigned long r2;
int fake = (flag & BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO);

kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;

s = getenv("machid");
if (s) {
strict_strtoul(s, 16, &machid);
printf("Using machid 0x%lx from environment\n", machid);
}

debug("## Transferring control to Linux (at address %08lx)" \
"...\n", (ulong) kernel_entry);
bootstage_mark(BOOTSTAGE_ID_RUN_OS);
announce_and_cleanup(fake);

if (IMAGE_ENABLE_OF_LIBFDT && images->ft_len)
r2 = (unsigned long)images->ft_addr;
else
r2 = gd->bd->bi_boot_params;

if (!fake)
kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
#endif
}
```

I am facing difficulty in understanding how `kernel_entry` is working here. Especially in the second-last line it is being used as:

```
   kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
```

So where is the definition of `kernel_entry()`? I failed to find in entire u-boot and kernel source code.

**Update**

I am rephrasing my question here:

Suppose `kernel_entry` is a pointer to a function and is being defined as:

```
bootm_headers_t *images
kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;
```

Then somewhere in the program it is being called as:

```
 kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
```

I understand being a pointer, `kernel_entry` should store an address of a function. But I want to understand what operations will be performed on the three arguments. Why do we have those arguments?

Comment: `kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;`

Comment: what operation will the function perform on those three arguments i.e int, int, uint?

Comment: It's not a function its a pointer cast, so you can call kernel_entry with 3 parameters, `int` for the first two and `uint` for the third

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain what exactly is happening in 'kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;'  and reply as an answer ?

Comment: Do you mind formatting the code so that it is readable?

Comment: @WernerHenze tried using 'code' , but not working

Comment: @user2799508 Formatting needs to be done by hand. You can use your preferred IDE for that and copy-paste the code here. "code" will only prepend a complete block of code with 4 spaces each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of `kernel_entry` variable and its type, which is a pointer to a function taking `int`, `int`, `uint` and returning `void` (probably the most confusing part), is here:

```
void (*kernel_entry)(int zero, int arch, uint params);
```

Assignment, `images->ep` is cast into desired signature function pointer and put into the variable:

```
kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;
```

Finally, the function is called:

```
kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
```

Please note that if CONFIG_ARM64 is defined, then the function `kernel_entry` points to has different signature:

```
void (*kernel_entry)(void *fdt_addr); //takes one void* param and returns void
```

Comment: kernel_entry is a pointer to 'a function'. where is that function ? it must a have a definition showing what to do with the three arguments...

Comment: the function is provided via `images->ep`. It's defined somewhere else, way before `boot_jump_linux` was called.

Comment: Also I could not find anything about ep . It should be a structure ?

Comment: The function definition is irrelevant. Just as you can cast `*int` to `*float`, you can cast function pointer to anything else. Clearly author of this code threw type-checking out of the window.

Comment: `ep` is a member of `bootm_headers_t` struct

Comment: So kernel_entry(0, machid, r2); will only pass three parameters to the function (defined somewhere), type cast, and save the pointer in kernel_entry?

Comment: It would pass those three parameters to the function and call it. type casting and saving the pointer was done in `kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;`

Comment: Perhaps you should learn more about pointers on common ones (pointers to variables). Pointers to functions are quite confusing, as they deal with multiple types at once, and their syntax is also not-so-clear.

Comment: ok. But one thing is still confusing. How do I find the function (pointed by kernel_entry), when I do not know its name ..

Comment: That's the point of the pointers: the name is no longer used. Here, I made an example for you: http://codepad.org/j5xnuy1N

Answer (score 1):

U-Boot has the kernel image in its addressable memory space, reads an address contained in that image (at images->ep), and branches to that entry point address.

The "definition of kernel_entry()" is actually in kernel source code, the label "start" at arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S is what you are looking for.

To understand the kernel boot process, IMO the definitive tutorial is chapter 5 of Hallinan "Embedded Linux Primer".

Comment: Thanks for the info. But actually there is no such file anywhere. Could you please cross check teh file name/location?

Comment: Also I found another .S file: arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S, which has thsi label.

Comment: Oops very sorry, my typo, it is arch/arm/boot/compressed/head.S. That "start" label is definitely correct for v3.14.3 on my Cortex-A9 target.