# In u-boot, kernel_entry points to which function?

Tags: c, u-boot

This is the function from u-boot:

```
static void boot_jump_linux(bootm_headers_t *images, int flag)
{
#ifdef CONFIG_ARM64
void (*kernel_entry)(void *fdt_addr);
int fake = (flag & BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO);

kernel_entry = (void (*)(void *fdt_addr))images->ep;

debug("## Transferring control to Linux (at address %lx)...\n",
(ulong) kernel_entry);
bootstage_mark(BOOTSTAGE_ID_RUN_OS);

announce_and_cleanup(fake);

if (!fake)
kernel_entry(images->ft_addr);
#else
unsigned long machid = gd->bd->bi_arch_number;
char *s;
void (*kernel_entry)(int zero, int arch, uint params);
unsigned long r2;
int fake = (flag & BOOTM_STATE_OS_FAKE_GO);

kernel_entry = (void (*)(int, int, uint))images->ep;

s = getenv("machid");
if (s) {
strict_strtoul(s, 16, &machid);
printf("Using machid 0x%lx from environment\n", machid);
}

debug("## Transferring control to Linux (at address %08lx)" \
"...\n", (ulong) kernel_entry);
bootstage_mark(BOOTSTAGE_ID_RUN_OS);
announce_and_cleanup(fake);

if (IMAGE_ENABLE_OF_LIBFDT && images->ft_len)
r2 = (unsigned long)images->ft_addr;
else
r2 = gd->bd->bi_boot_params;

if (!fake)
kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
#endif
}
```

I understood from the related question: [Trying to understand the usage of function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24409821/trying-to-understand-the-usage-of-function-pointer) that `kernel_entry`is a pointer to **a** function. Can someone help me understand where that function is defined? I don't even know the name of this function so I failed to `grep`it.

**NOTE:** The entire u-boot source code is [here](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/blob/master/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed `kernel_entry` is a function pointer. It is initialized from the `ep` field of the piece of data passed in called `images`, of type `bootm_header_t`. The definition of that `struct` is in `include/image.h`. This is the definition of a bootable image header, ie the header of a kernel image which contain the basic info to boot that image from the boot loader. Obviously, to start it, you need a program entry point, similarly to the main function in regular C programs.

In that structure, the entry point is simply defined as a memory address (`unsigned long`), which the code you listed cast into that function pointer.

That structure as been obtained from loading the first blocks of the image file on disk, whose location is known already by the boot loader.

Hence the actual code pointed by that function pointer belongs to a different binary, and the definition of the function must be located in a different source code. For a linux kernel, this entry point is an assembly hand coded function, whose source is in `head.S`. This function being highly arch dependent, you will find many files of that name implementing it  accross the kernel tree.

Comment: But there should be a definition of the function which is pointed by kernel_entry(int, int, uint ). where is that?

Comment: It's in the source code of that kernel image, not in the boot loader.

Comment: I agree. Do you think that code (function defintion) could be an assembly code?